# Using Google Maps API to dynamically display delivery-time zones?

Tags: google-maps, api, dynamic

I'm looking to replicate the functionality from the [UPS Ground Map](https://www.ups.com/maps/results) which will allow users to enter a zipcode, then dynamically show delivery times by region. I know I need travel times by state data to do this. But lets say I did, could this be possible to do over the Google Maps API if I had this data?

If yes, could anyone offer any advice on how to accomplish this? I'm not looking for code handouts, but any references/pointing me to useful documentation would be great.